# Integration of Glide along with Room database, GlideApp Class is not generating (Glide 4.7.1)

Tags: android, android-glide

First I Integrated Room database and stored some information to db which contain some image URL, Now i need to show this images in ImageViews.

And now trying do so using glide, added the dependency and annotation processor,

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'

getting no compilation error, After building/syncing project the GlideApp should be generated. but getting error Can not resolve symbol 'GlideApp'

You can check my code here
https://bitbucket.org/G-yan/roomdbexperiments/src/master/

Comment: @Archie G. Quiñones

I tried to use GlideModule anotation in RDbGlideModule Class Now My GlideApp class generated but images are not loading

Comment: Having the same issue, have you resolved this @Gyanaranjan Biswal @

Comment: Ya, try adding  @GlideModule

Comment: @ – Kunal You can check the working code here https://bitbucket.org/G-yan/roomdbexperiments/src/master/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add @GlideModule Annotation to your Glide Module.